# How to find the duplicates in database entries in laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to find the duplicates in the database entries using laravel.But my result is incorrect please help to find it.

```
$query    =    DB::table('tbl_documents as td')
        ->leftjoin('tbl_document_types as tc','td.document_type_id','=','tc.document_type_id')
        //->leftjoin('tbl_documents_columns as tdc','td.document_id','=','tdc.document_id')
        ->leftjoin('tbl_departments as tdp','td.department_id','=','tdp.department_id')
        ->leftjoin('tbl_stacks as ts','ts.stack_id','=','td.stack_id')
        ->select('td.document_name','td.document_file_name','tc.document_type_id','td.document_type_id','td.stack_id','tdp.department_id')->havingRaw('count(*)>1')
        ->where('td.document_type_id',$doctypeid)
        ->get();
```

Comment: From which table are you finding dublicates? tbl_documents, tbl_document_types, or tbl_stacks ?

Comment: I need duplicate entries from tbl_documents

Comment: Which field you want duplicates? `document_name` or `document_file_name`

Comment: when i changed my code to groupby(document_file_name) it shows only single entry of the duplicates.I want all duplicate entries

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this**

```
$results = DB::table('tbl_documents')->whereIn('document_file_name', function ( $query ) {
            $query->select('document_file_name')->from('tbl_documents')->groupBy('document_file_name')->havingRaw('count(*) > 1');
        })->get()->toArray();

return $results;
```